Is there a name for a psychotic phenomenon, similar to auditory hallucinations where "voices" manifest as silent thoughts instead?
Individuals suffering from (drug induced) or natural schizophrenic symptoms often have auditory hallucinations in the form of persons / characters talking or conversing manifesting as actually audible sounds that are almost indistinguishable from real sounds of the physical world.
I was wondering if there is a name for a (i guess) psychotic phenomenon that is very similar
but instead of manifesting as audible (loud) voice, the same persons conversations manifest as silent thoughts.
They have the same characteristics, the voice of the thought sounds the same and the content of the conversations is the same.
The only difference to auditory hallucinations is that the thoughts are silent (even though they have a characteristic and identifiable "voice").
I'm wondering if there's a distinction between these two forms of (apparently) schizophrenic symptoms and if this may as well originate from a dopamine discrepancy (mesolimbic D2 hyperactivity / prefrontal hypoactivity) or if such a phenomenon would more likely be a thought pattern adapted from experiencing schizophrenic auditory hallucinations over a long period of time?

Auditory hallucinations are sometimes described as coming "from the mind" rather than being attributed to an outside source (such as a radio or TV). I don't believe these have any separate term to describe them, that's just one trait of an auditory hallucination that varies from person to person. Is that what you're asking about? Separately, "self-talk" or "internal dialogue" is not ordinarily considered a hallucination when someone attributes it to their own self rather than some other source. There's also thought insertion.

@BryanKrause Thank you very much for your expertise. Yes that's precisely what I was asking about. So I guess the underlying root cause (DH) might cause both phenomena. I was thinking it may be possible that being exposed to auditory hallucinations for too long may condition the brain to exhibit similar thought patterns even though no D2 hyperactivity is present anymore. Like leaving an imprint. Similar to how CBT might change thought patterns. The thought insertion also covers an interesting phenomenon I didn't yet know about. Thanks a lot!
